# Tracking multiple list entries for individual users

Tags: custom-list, multiple-values

I have a training registration list in SP2013 for one training session that is offered every month. Users can sign up to attend multiple times (for example, if they were on leave and/or need a refresher).

I want to create a new list that has one entry for each user, and tracks what sessions each has attended (rather than just sorting the original registration list and counting how many times Jane Smith appears). What's the best way to pull information from the registration list into a new list that displays this information?

Looking for something like:

Name > Session 1 > Session 2

Jane Smith > July 2015 > February 2016

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situations I use a Courses Attended list. When user updates the Registration list a workflow does the following:

1. Checks if user exists in the Courses Attended list. It is assigning ID field from that list to a variable to the user ID in question and checking if it is empty.
2. If it doesn't exist, I create a new entry for that user, with the current course date as the first course date.
3. If entry exists, then update courses attended field, appending the latest course date. For your requirement perhaps I would use a Single Line Text field and literally append the new date to the old. Although I must admit it is not a very elegant solution, but I think it is acceptable for reporting purposes.